# Create a Puppy class with private property name and both a getter and a setter for that property called getName and setName. The constructor should

Tags: javascript, constructor, getter-setter, setter, getter

JavaScript is very much not my thing, for those of you who answer these questions, you are absolute life savers.

**Create a Puppy class with private property name and both a getter and a setter for that property called getName and setName. The constructor should take a parameter to initialize the private property.**

*My code:*

```
public class Puppy {
private String name;

public Puppy(String name) {
  setName(name);
}

public String getName() {
  return Name;
}

public String setName(String name) {
  this.name=name;
}
```

*Screenshot:*
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgRGM.png)

Comment: It looks like you are writing java not  javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apparently missed the salient word 'private' when I answered this question.  The code I posted created public instance variables.

```
    class Puppy {
        constructor(n) {
            // private property
            var name = n

            // methods that use private property
            this.getName = () => {return name}
            this.setName = (n) => {name = n}

            // public property
            this.nickname = n
        }

        // methods that use public property
        setNickname(n) { this.nickname = n }
        getNickname() { return this.nickname }
    }

    p = new Puppy("fido")

    console.log("p.name",p.name) // undefined, not accessible
    console.log("p.getName()",p.getName()) // fido
    console.log("p.getNickname()",p.getNickname()) // fido

    console.log("---")

    p.name = "barker" // defines a new property on this instance of Puppy
    console.log("p.name",p.name) // barker
    console.log("p.getName() ",p.getName()) // doesn't change private name fido

    console.log("---")

    p.setName("fuzz") // change private name
    console.log("p.getName()",p.getName()) // fuzz
    console.log("p.getNickname()",p.getNickname()) // fido

    console.log("---")

    p.nickname = "chewy" // set public property directly
    console.log("p.getNickname()",p.getNickname()) // chewy
```

Comment: An extension is how to use private properties with getters and setters as they aren't declared within the function body of the constructor. Also, this puts *getName* and *setName* on every instance, they aren't inherited (*cf* instance vs class methods).